# Google Sheet API (JS) : Not write blanks cells

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Don't know how i can bypass empty cells...?
It write "undefined" on empty cells.

row[0] == "" don't seems to be good.

Thanks in advance.

```
function appendPre(message) {
    var pre = document.getElementById('content');
    var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n'+'\n');
    pre.appendChild(textContent);
  }

  function listMajors() {
    gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
      spreadsheetId: '1gHFaUxQX3ZQ7-nJ7ikviLojgNa06xJjFR9LSYzjFsLY',
      range: 'Feuille 1!A2:A99',
    }).then(function(response) {
      var range = response.result;
      if (range.values.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0 ; i < range.values.length; i++) {
          var row = range.values[i];
          while (row[0] == ""){
            i++;
          }
          appendPre(row[0]);

        }
      }
      else {
        appendPre();
      }
    }, function(response) {
      appendPre();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Did you try `row[0] == null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

- Blanks are not returned by the api. If `A1:A3` is requested and `A2` is empty, the returned array is `[["A1"],[],["A3"]]`. So, `row[0]` is `undefined` and `undefined` !=="".

#### Solutions:

- Check `row`'s length before indexing into it

  ```
  if (row.length) appendPre(row[0]);
  ```
- Alternatively, prefilter the values:

  ```
  let values = range.values;
  values.filter(row=>row.length)
  ```